# Read elements from XMLList in flex

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex3, flex4.5

[image]

is it possible to read elements what i have circled in image. I need this because XmlLists what i receive from the system is dynamic.Their elements are not static.I can't use methods like

```
for each(var item:XML in dp)
{
    var element:String=item.@date.toString;
}
```

i cannot use @date always because XMLList content change always. date , open , close names are not getting always .

Answer (score 1):

This is my sample XML

```
        private var testXML:XML=<main>
                                <item name= "agent1" tag="cpu" value="39"/>
                                <item name= "agent2" tag="cpu" value="17"/>
                                <item name= "agent3" tag="cpu" value="27"/>
                                <item name= "agent4" tag="cpu" value="39"/>
                                <item name= "agent5" tag="cpu" value="17"/>
                                <item name= "agent6" tag="cpu" value="27"/>
                               </main>;
```

This sample code shows how i achieved

```
        var List:XMLList=testXML.children();

        var attr:XMLList=List.attributes();

        for(var i:Number=0;i<List[0].attributes().length();i++)
        {
            Alert.show(attr[i].name()); 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can use this syntax

```
var str_attr:String = "@date"; // or any things you define
for each(var item:XML in dp)
{
    var element:String=item[str_attr].toString();
}
```

Comment: I can't use above method.

Comment: i cannt use this method " var str_attr:String = "@date"  "

because "date" element name is dyamic. I want to find a element names inside tags.